# Send Form to users using Firebase Realtime-Database

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am almost done fixing a huge problem I have been having the last few weeks. Long story short I'm trying to be able to send array data to my Firebase Database. I will show what the send button is currently sending when I press send:

[image: database]

I would like the zero to be every user's id (one node for each row). The number of users and who they are is determined by a table and the child values to be the values in the array.

Here is the code for the function that sends to firebase:

```
@IBAction func sendButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    
    let companyNameC = companyNameTextFieldConsiderations.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    let companyDescriptionC = companyDescriptionTextFieldConsiderations.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    
    let today = Date()
    let formatter1 = DateFormatter()
    formatter1.dateFormat = "MMM d y"
    print(formatter1.string(from: today))
    let todaysDate = formatter1.string(from: today)
            
    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: "MY STORAGE URL HERE")
    let imageName = companyNameTextFieldConsiderations.text!
    let storageCompanyRef = storageRef.child("Company_Image_Considerations").child("\(todaysDate)").child(imageName)
    let companyDescriptionTextFieldText = companyDescriptionTextFieldConsiderations.text
    let dateToStart = startDateTextFieldConsiderations.text
    let dateToDecide = endDateTextFieldConsiderations.text
    let companyRef = Database.database().reference().child("Considerations").child("\(todaysDate)").child(imageName)
    let numberOfPeopleCells = ConsiderationsTestViewController.people
    let considerationInfluencerRef = Database.database().reference().child("Considerations").child("\(todaysDate)").child(imageName).child("Users").child("\(numberOfPeopleCells.startIndex)")
    
     let values = ["Feed_Quantity": "feedTFC", "Story_Quantity": "storyTFC", "Compensation": "compensationTFC"]
    
        guard let imageSelected = self.CompanyImage.image else {
            print ("Avatar is nil")
            return
                }
                   
                var dict: Dictionary<String, Any> = [
                    "Company Image": "",
                    "Company Description": companyDescriptionTextFieldText!,
                    "Start Date": dateToStart!,
                    "Decision Date": dateToDecide! ]
    
                   
        guard let imageData = imageSelected.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5) else {
            return
                }
    
                let metadata = StorageMetadata()
                metadata.contentType = "image/jpeg"
                storageCompanyRef.putData(imageData, metadata: metadata, completion:
                { (StorageMetadata, error) in
                if (error != nil) {
                return
                    }
                            
                storageCompanyRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
                if let metadateImage = url?.absoluteString {
                dict["Company Image"] = metadateImage
                   
                companyRef.updateChildValues(dict, withCompletionBlock:  {
                (error, ref) in
                if error == nil {
                print("Done")
                return
                    }
                  }
                )
               }
             }
                            
                                   storageRef.updateMetadata(metadata) { metadata, error in
                                    if error != nil {
                                    //Uh-oh, an error occurred!
                                    } else {
                                    // Updated metadata for 'images/forest.jpg' is returned
                                }
                            }
                        })
    
    considerationInfluencerRef.updateChildValues(values as [AnyHashable : Any]) { (error, ref) in
    if error != nil {
    print(error ?? "")
    return
                       }
    
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
}
```

I can't seem to be able to reference the atIndexPath.row. Then I would use the UID from each cell to create a node and then have each indePath.row data append the children values.

What is the best course of action?

EDIT: Here is the struct for people:

```
import UIKit

struct Person {
   var Name: String?
   var PostNumber: String?
   var StoryNumber: String?
   var Compensation: String?
   var ProfileImageUrl: String?
   var userID: String?
}
```

and here is the table code:

```
extension ConsiderationsTestViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    
    return ConsiderationsTestViewController.people.count
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
return 72
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: AddPersonCell, for: indexPath) as! ConsiderationsCell
    
    let numberOfPeopleCells = ConsiderationsTestViewController.people[indexPath.row]
    
    
    cell.nameLabelC.text = numberOfPeopleCells.Name
    cell.feedLabelC.text = numberOfPeopleCells.PostNumber
    cell.storyLabelC.text = numberOfPeopleCells.StoryNumber
    cell.compensationLabelC.text = numberOfPeopleCells.Compensation
    cell.userImage.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(urlString: numberOfPeopleCells.ProfileImageUrl!)
    
    cell.userImage.layer.cornerRadius = 25
    
    cell.nameLabelC.numberOfLines = 0
    
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if (editingStyle == .delete) {
        
        ConsiderationsTestViewController.people.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        // handle delete (by removing the data from your array and updating the tableview)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT:

Here is an example of the array when there is 3 users:

```
 3 elements
 ▿ 0 : Person
 ▿ Name : Optional<String>
  - some : "Person's Name1"
 ▿ PostNumber : Optional<String>
  - some : "1"
 ▿ StoryNumber : Optional<String>
  - some : "1"
 ▿ Compensation : Optional<String>
  - some : "1"
 ▿ ProfileImageUrl : Optional<String>
  - some : "PROFILEIMAGE URL HERE"
 ▿ userID : Optional<String>
  - some : "B2Z4DlZ8RucvEQhz2NSUkquqc5P2"

 ▿ 1 : Person
 ▿ Name : Optional<String>
  - some : "Person's Name2"
 ▿ PostNumber : Optional<String>
  - some : "1"
 ▿ StoryNumber : Optional<String>
  - some : "11"
 ▿ Compensation : Optional<String>
  - some : "1"
 ▿ ProfileImageUrl : Optional<String>
  - some : "PROFILEIMAGE URL HERE"
 ▿ userID : Optional<String>
  - some : "Lbn9HL1WIpZTMFzpGWAXy7Ra0EA2"

 ▿ 2 : Person
 ▿ Name : Optional<String>
  - some : "Person's Name3"
 ▿ PostNumber : Optional<String>
  - some : "1"
 ▿ StoryNumber : Optional<String>
  - some : "1"
 ▿ Compensation : Optional<String>
  - some : "1"
 ▿ ProfileImageUrl : Optional<String>
  - some : "PROFILEIMAGE URL HERE"
 ▿ userID : Optional<String>
  - some : "NE6WVUfF6WQjJT9eeVSJgfvrrZW2"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is your goal (as stated in your question)

> I would like the zero to be the user's id

On this line

```
let considerationInfluencerRef = Database.database().reference().child("Considerations")
                           .child("\(todaysDate)")
                           .child(imageName)
                           .child("Users")
                           .child("\(numberOfPeopleCells.startIndex)")
```

change the ending child node from this

```
.child("\(numberOfPeopleCells.startIndex)")
```

to this

```
.child(Auth.auth().currentUser.uid)
```

To expand a little, you should be using a dataSource array to back your tableView

```
var myDatasource = [Person]()
```

so if you have three people (using your structure)

```
myDatasource[0] = person 0
myDatasource[1] = person 1
myDatasource[2] = person 2
```

So just iterate over the array, get the person and their uid and write the data. Something like this (don't copy paste, did this on my iPad)

```
myDatasource.forEach { person in
   let uid = person.userID
   let dict = [
      "name": person.name,
      "postNumber": person.postNumber
   ]

   let ref = let considerationInfluencerRef = Database.database().......child(uid)
   ref.setData(dict)
}
```

Comment: Hey Jay. That's my fault. I didn't explain clear enough. I would like the node to be all the users uid in the table. Each row has a user and their UID in the struct for that cell.

Comment: The pattern is the same. Once you've established the parent node, then all of the child data written will be to that node. My answer shows how to use the current userId but if the id's are stored in an array, just iterate over that array, reading each uid from it, craft the parent node as shown in my answer and then write the child data.

Comment: All of the data I want to use is in a struct. Each indexPath.row has a user and information tied to them. In the edited area it shows how the array looks. I am not sure how to make each parent node under users, all the users in the table.

Comment: I apologize Jay. I didn't mean to edit your answer.

Comment: @CoderCoop I added a bit more code to the answer. Just iterate over the dataSource array, grab the persons uid, craft a ref and store the dict. that will results in each child node having the users uid as the key, and then the child data as you requested.

Comment: Ok! How do I do this if there could be an infinite number of users?

Comment: @CoderCoop That `.forEach` will iterate over the array regardless of how many there are 0 ..... TO INFINITY!

Comment: Hey Jay. Where should I be putting this code? I keep getting different errors. I'm almost done haha super sorry for the headache.

Comment: @CoderCoop It's hard to say specifically where to put it without knowing your entire project. Assuming you have a dataSource that contains your data (shown as myDataSource in the answer) it would be whenever you want to write out all of that data here *I would like the zero to be every user's id (one node for each row)*

Comment: All good Jay. I was able to figure it out and it worked!!! I am now trying my best to call the information on the users side. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: Hey Jay. Sorry to bug you I have two questions that I could use your help with! I'll link them here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63419647/reload-collectionview-from-another-controller-returning-nil?noredirect=1#comment112205598_63419647. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63454330/access-multiple-nodes-in-firebase-database

Answer (score 0):

It's all-but impossible to do this sort of thing in Firebase.

Change to Firestore.

It will take you a tiny fraction of the time.

It's always worth remembering that Firebase is "Absolutely amazing and incredible, but often totally useless."

There are mnany things you just can't realistically do in Firebase.

Making such architectural decisions is tough and critical.

Moreover, just change to an **ordinary relational database** for this.

You'll be done in a few minutes, it's so easy.

(Yes, sync is harder but it can be done.  Just use PubNub or the like, or even Firebase raw "only as a syncer" to sync.)

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that. I have all my users and everything in my storage and would have to rewrite so much code because I have a messaging function and I'm not sure how to get it to Firestore. is there another way to do this? I need to be able to send each user in the table their row information as well as information outside of a table.

Comment: @CoderCoop I am not sure I agree with this answer - mostly because this task is pretty easy in either the Real Time Database or Firestore - also changing over to a *ordinary* local relational database (MySQL? Posgresql?) would result in not having real time updates, user authentication built in, cloud functions, online first ability and a host of other features. Not saying it's wrong, just saying that due to the vagueness of the question, an opinion-based answer could be off base :-)

Comment: @Jay - BTW obviously I meant using an rdb .. simply MySql is great *in the cloud* ...  As you know this is incredibly widely available and you can spin one up in 2 clicks from here, AWS is all you need.  Notice my final paragraph (in braces) which fully explains - in detail! - how to easily sync that these days.

Comment: @Jay , you said *"this task is pretty easy..."*  TBH I may not have perfectly understood the task since the explanation is a bit long and I glossed.

Comment: @CoderCoop - you mention moving your data etc.  Will take 10-20 minutes .. or something is dreadfully wrong  :/  the way to drastically speed up development is almost always a "huge change" ...