# Access Multiple Nodes in Firebase Database

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, firebase-realtime-database, struct

I am having a hard time pulling all my data from one of my nodes in my firebase database.

Here is how the node looks like in Firebase:

```
Considerations
     -MEdUNZwVrsDW3dTrE6N
        Company Description: 
        Company Image: 
        Company Name: 
        Decision Date: 
        Start Date: 
        Users
           B2Z4DlZ8RucvEQhz2NSUkquqc5P2
              Compensation: 
              PostNumber: 
              StoryNumber:
```

Under users there are going to be multiple people with different values for the compensation, post number, and storynumber. I have each user having a node called "user-considerations" that tags the unique id of the consideration each user is attached on and places it under their UID and tags a 1 next to it as the value. I am trying to access each specific user's info along with the other info in the node. Here is my code that I am using to call the information along with the struct I a using to capture the information:

STRUCT:

```
import UIKit

class ConsiderationInfo: NSObject {
    var companyName: String?
    var companyImage: String?
    var companyDescription: String?
    var decisionDate: String?
    var startDate: String?
    var compensation: String?
    var postNumber: String?
    var storyNumber: String?
}
```

CODE FOR OBSERVING INFO:

```
 func updateConsiderationsArray() {
    
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("user-considerations").child(uid!)
            
            ref.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
            
                    let considerationId = snapshot.key
                    let considerationReference = Database.database().reference().child("Considerations").child(considerationId)
            
                    considerationReference.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

                    if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                    let considerationInfo = ConsiderationInfo()
                    //self.setValuesForKeys(dictionary)
                    considerationInfo.companyName = dictionary["Company Name"] as? String
                    considerationInfo.companyImage = dictionary["Company Image"] as? String
                    considerationInfo.companyDescription = dictionary["Company Description"] as? String
                    considerationInfo.decisionDate = dictionary["Decision Date"] as? String
                    considerationInfo.startDate = dictionary["Start Date"] as? String
                
                    self.considerationsInfo.append(considerationInfo)
                    self.considerationName.append(considerationInfo.companyName!)
                    self.filteredConsiderations.append(considerationInfo.companyName!)
                        
                        self.considerationCollectionView.reloadData()
                }
            }, withCancel: nil)
        })
    }
```

I am trying to access the information under the user specific node, i.e. the specific user's compensation post number and story number. I am unaware of how to access all of this to append the struct.

Here is the node with the user-considerations:

[image: user node]

Comment: The code is poorly formatted and hard to read can you fix. Also, please stick with coding standards. Class and Struct names are uppercased first char. vars are lowercased first char. Also, why NSObject? This is swift. Also, what's up with the code after `withCancel` as it doesn't do anything. You don't need this `DispatchQueue.main.async {` within firebase closures as UI calls are always done on the main thread. Why are you leaving observers on all those nodes - make one change in your database and everything is reloaded on top of what's already there. See `.observeSingleEvent`

Comment: Hey Jay. Thank you for the help. Like I mentioned I am new to coding (I have never taken a coding class) so I am unaware of certain protocols with uppercase and NSObject. I am trying to be able to set all the strings in the class Consideration by reading the specific company node. I've made an edit that shows how I am setting up a node called user-consideration that marks the company's consideration uid with a one under each user's uid

Comment: It's good to include your structure, but include it as text if possible - that way we can copy and paste it into an answer instead of retyping. It was pretty obvious what that part of the structure was but thanks for including it. If you can address the rest of the issues I mentioned it would help; fix your vars, format your code in the question and remove/update excess code. It's so hard to read we still don't know what's going on with the code at the bottom of the question. Keep in mind that value will cause an event to fire any time there's a change and add on to or overwrite existing data.

Comment: Hey Jay. I removed the reload data and it wouldn't load collection views. I made the vars lowercased and I removed the second observe after the withCancel. What else do I need to do so you can help me?

Comment: I didn't say to remove reload data. Please re-read all of the above comments. Coding is a very precise discipline and rushing through tasks and omitting important points just causes long term headaches. Slow down and correct your *actual code* in your project, not just update the code in the question; yeah you lowercased the properties but now the rest of your code won't work `considerationInfo.CompanyName`. We still don't know what the code after `withCancel` is for. Also we what does this mean *it erases the other node information*? Erases what? Firebase? Something else?

Comment: Hey Jay. Thank you for the help. I updated the question hopefully this is will make it easier to answer the question. I really owe you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it sits, I am really not seeing anything super wrong with the code but there are few things that could be changed to make it more streamlined.

I would first change the Consideration Info class to make it more self contained. Add a convenience initializer to handle a firebase snapshot directly with some error checking.

```
class ConsiderationInfo: NSObject {
    var companyName = ""

    convenience init(withSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        self.init()
        self.companyName = withSnapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "Company Name").value as? String ?? "No Company Name"
    }
}
```

I would also suggest removing the .childAdded and .observe events unless you specifically want to be notified of future changes. Use .value and .observeSingleEvent instead. Keeping in mind that .childAdded iterates over each node in your database one at a time - .value reads them in all at the same time. If there is a limited amount of data, .value works well.

```
    func updateConsiderationsArray() {
        let fbRef = Database.database().reference()
        let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        let ref = fbRef.child("user_considerations").child(uid)
        ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
            let allUidsSnap = snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
            for uidSnap in allUidsSnap {
                let considerationId = uidSnap.key
                let considerationReference = fbRef.child("Considerations").child(considerationId)
                considerationReference.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
                    let considerationInfo = ConsiderationInfo(withSnapshot: snapshot)
                    self.considerationArray.append(considerationInfo)
                    // update your collectionView
                })
            }
        })
    }
```

What I am doing in the above is reading in the single node from user_considerations, which looks like this according to your quuestion

```
user_considerations
   some_user_uid
      a_user_uid
      a_user_uid
```

and then mapping each child user to an array to maintain order

```
let allUidsSnap = snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
```

and then iterating over each, getting the uid (the key) of each node and getting that nodes data from the Considerations node.

Comment: Hey Jay. Thank you for the help. Will I be able to read and write the information in the consideration node and the user specific information for each user?

Comment: @CoderCoop Was the explanation in the answer not clear? The code iterates over the child notes in user_considerations, gets each user id and then reads those specific nodes from Considerations - that's what you wanted, correct? I didn't address any writing of data as that wasn't part of the question.

Comment: That's my fault for not making myself clear in the question. I want to be able to read each thing in the consideration node as well as the current user specific info. For example I want each user to be able to read Company Description: 
        Company Image: 
        Company Name: 
        Decision Date: 
        Start Date: But then depending on the user, they can read their own specific info as well i.e. be able to observe multiple nodes.

Comment: @CoderCoop The code in my answer could be used for both tasks. I would suggest implementing it as is to read multiple nodes (per your question) and then modifying to just read a single specific user node instead of loading them all into an array.

Comment: I unfortunately need an array because I am using the array count to populate the collection view item count. The collection view is going to hold all the considerations and use their company image stored in my firebase storage as their item image. When the use taps a consideration, it will take them to a view controller with the company information as well as the current user's specific information. Does that make any sense or am I confusing?(Not a dig, I understand what I am saying because I'm asking lol)

Comment: @CoderCoop Not sure what  you're talking about. Using an array as a datasource is standard practice and my answer populated it here `self.considerationArray.append(considerationInfo)`

Comment: All good! How would you use your code to access all the information? Thats where I'm confused.

Comment: @CoderCoop Not sure what *all the information* means. All the information like companyName, companyImage, companyDescription? If so, that's shown in the `ConsiderationInfo` model presented in my answer. If you mean in the `user_considerations` node, you're code only reads one uid - and so does mine. Other than that, there is no other information so... can you clarify?